# Discord.py and OS module in Discord Bot (sorry description should explain better)

Tags: python, macos, discord.py

Basically I came up with this idea to allow for certain apps or features on my laptop to be operated through a private discord server. The bot is still in testing phase so I'm using System Preferences because it can be opened and closed the fastest.

Anyway I'm surprised to see that the bot has somewhat worked and I am able to close apps from my Discord server, but I also want to be notified whenever certain apps have been opened. As you'll see in the image I have attached: [Discord Bot in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfvhI.png), whenever I open System Preferences, it doesn't send me a message until I say something in chat. It will keep saying "Someone has opened System Preferences" every time I say anything unless I close it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
 
  # Sytem Preferences
  SysPref=(is_running("System Preferences"))
  if SysPref == True:
    await message.channel.send("Someone has opened System Preferences!")

  if message.content.startswith("!close System_Preferences") and SysPref == True:
    os.system("pkill System Preferences")
    await message.channel.send("System Preferences closed!")
  elif message.content.startswith("!close System_Preferences") and SysPref == False:
    await message.channel.send("System Preferences is not open")
```

I used this AppleScript incorporated into Python from somewhere on stack overflow:

```
def is_runnning(app):
    count = int(subprocess.check_output(["osascript",
          "-e", "tell application \"System Events\"",
          "-e", "count (every process whose name is \"" + app + "\")",
          "-e", "end tell"]).strip())
return count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand you code perfectly but I think maybe you are not returning after an if statement. So it continues to execute the next if statement as well. This may sound dumb but try it

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
 
  # Sytem Preferences
  SysPref=(is_running("System Preferences"))
  if SysPref == True:
    await message.channel.send("Someone has opened System Preferences!")
    return

  if message.content.startswith("!close System_Preferences") and SysPref == True:
    os.system("pkill System Preferences")
    await message.channel.send("System Preferences closed!")
    return

  elif message.content.startswith("!close System_Preferences") and SysPref == False:
    await message.channel.send("System Preferences is not open")
    return
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but that's not what I want. I tried it anyway, but instead it didn't feedback anything. I need the bot to tell me when System Preferences, as soon as I open it. Right now it only does so if I text something first.